# VB.NET erroring when passing Oracle Parameter Type PLSQLAssociativeArray

Tags: vb.net, oracle, plsql

I have a oracle stored procedure that looks like:

```
PROCEDURE GET_PART_CHARACTERISTICS (v_catalog_nos_ IN CatalogNos, 
                                    Parts_Char_Cursor out sys_refcursor) AS
BEGIN
    OPEN Parts_Char_Cursor FOR
    SELECT catalog_no, characteristic_code, unit_meas, attr_value 
    FROM IFSAPP.SALES_PART_CHARACTERISTIC     
    WHERE CATALOG_NO IN (select * from table(v_catalog_nos_)); 
END GET_PART_CHARACTERISTICS;
```

This is then called via VB.NET using:

```
Dim cmd As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand()
                    cmd.Connection = conn
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmd.CommandText = "dci_sales_group_part_api.get_part_characteristics"

                    Dim CatalogNosParam As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter()
                    CatalogNosParam.ParameterName = "v_catalog_nos_"
                    CatalogNosParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                    CatalogNosParam.OracleDbType = Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2
                    CatalogNosParam.Size = 100
                    Dim CatalogNoArr(0) As String
                    CatalogNoArr(0) = .Item("catalog_no")
                    CatalogNosParam.Value = CatalogNoArr
                    CatalogNosParam.CollectionType = Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(CatalogNosParam)

                    Dim partscharParam As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter()
                    partscharParam.ParameterName = "Parts_Char_Cursor"
                    partscharParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                    partscharParam.OracleDbType = Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.RefCursor
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(partscharParam)

                    Dim da As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter(cmd)

                    da.Fill(dsPartCharacteristics, "PartCharacteristics")
```

I am getting an error that states: "**ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_PART_CHARACTERISTICS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored**"

The CatalogNos type is declared as:

```
`create or replace TYPE CATALOGNOS AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);`
```

I am not sure why this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about DataAccess, but the OracleClient didn't like it if you omitted the colon (:) in the parameter name.

For example: `CatalogNosParam.ParameterName = ":v_catalog_nos_"`